# Django: session_key is an empty string

Tags: python, django, mixpanel

I'm using an analytics platform to track user interactions, and want to associate events by session id so I can track individual users' behaviors. So, I am using `request.session.session_key` as the user id I'm passing the event logging function. I don't use the session for anything else, and am not saving or modifying variables. I did set up middleware correctly, so far so good.

However, when I check the analytics platform, I see that the id is often (but not always) blank. I looked up some answers, and thought I could solve this by running `request.session.save()` before accessing the `session_key`. However, I can't run `.save()` because I'm not actually modifying any session variables, so Django throws an error.

What do I need to do to make sure the session always has an id?

---

Some code from my very simple get view:

```py
def get(self, req: HttpRequest):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        # this is where I tried req.session.save()
        mixpanel.track(
            req.session.session_key,
            "Form Page Displayed",
            {"path": req.path, "route": req.method},
        )
        return render(req, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

Comment: What is the error that Django throws?

Comment: Strangely enough, it's not throwing it anymore today. `session.save()` now works fine, and seems to be fixing it.